# Dependency Injection Involving Struct types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-4.6

I have a class as shown below,

```
public class AccessToken : IAuthToken
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AccessToken"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token">The token.</param>
    /// <param name="validTo">The valid to.</param>
    public AccessToken(string token, DateTimeOffset validTo)
    {
        ValidTo = validTo;
        Token = token;
    }

    ///<inheritdoc />
    public DateTimeOffset ValidTo { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the RAW Jwt token value. 
    /// This value is encoded and represents the Jwt token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The token.
    /// </value>
    public string Token { get; private set; }
}
```

The DI code goes like this,

```cs
return services
    .AddTransient<IAuthToken, AccessToken>()
    .AddTransient<IAuthTokenService, AuthTokenService>()
    .AddSingleton<IIdentityDiscovery, IdentityDiscovery>()
    .AddTransient<IIdentityTokenClient, IdentityTokenClient>()
    .AddTransient<IDiscoveryClientRetryPolicy, DiscoveryClientRetryPolicy>()
    .AddTransient<ITokenClientRetryPolicy, TokenClientRetryPolicy>()
    .AddSingleton<IRetryPolicyOptions>(provider => retryOptions);
```

The whole thing is packaged as a nuget. When this DI code is called from .net461 it works fine but when used in net core 6, I get an error stating it's unable to resolve type string and `DateTimeOffset`. I tried to inject a dummy string and the string error vanished but the struct DateTimeOffset persisted. Does .net6 interpret this DI in a different way?

Comment: That reaction from the system sounds reasonable to me. Everything injected into the constructor needs to be found or creatable via the servicecollection. Why did it work in an earlier framework version in the first place? What would have been injected there?

Comment: Did you inject a IAccessToken actually anywhere in your system? Maybe its actually never used and therefore was ignored in earlier versions but now the system checks if the registration makes any sense.

Comment: I don't believe that it worked fine in .NET 4.6.1. Perhaps in that version of your code, the services collection wasn't validated, while within the developer environment of ASP.NET Core 3 and up, all registrations are validated. Trying to resolve an `IAuthToken` in your .NET 4.6.1 application still cause an error. It simply can't work because of the reason Ralf mentioned.

Comment: Thank you guys. Is there a way I can inject a dummy struct? I cannot change the nuget code base as of now. This was an old code and you are right that the AccessToken injection was actually not needed. I just want to keep things as are in the nuget and continue with a dummy inject into the DateTimeOffset which does not seem to be possible for struct types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes in your nuget package tries to resolve this `IAuthToken` instance then you can add the following registration to your main app to override the registration that comes from the nuget. The registration order is important, so be sure to execute service registration from your nuget first.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IAuthToken, AccessToken>(
    serviceProvider =>
    {
        // You can resolve any service that can provide the token and validTo parameters.
        var tokenInfoProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<...>();

        // Get the parameter values.
        // Either from the tokenInfoProvider or specify it directly here.
        string token = String.Empty;
        DateTimeOffset validTo = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1);

        // Create and return the access token instance.
        return new AccessToken(token, validTo);
    }
);
```

If only the app tries to resolve an `IAuthToken` then I would suggest to create a factory (e.g. `IAccessTokenFactory`) that you can use to create the `AccessToken` instance with specific ctor parameters dynamically. Then register its implementation and inject `IAccessTokenFactory` where you need to get a new `IAuthToken` instance. So that you can keep your nuget code as it is now.

```cs
public interface IAccessTokenFactory
{
    IAuthToken Create(string token, DateTimeOffset validTo);
}

public class AccessTokenFactory : IAccessTokenFactory
{
    public IAuthToken Create(string token, DateTimeOffset validTo)
    {
        return new AccessToken(token, validTo);
    }
}

// register this instead of the AccessToken
services.AddSingleton<IAccessTokenFactory, AccessTokenFactory>();
```